# Get lambda input in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have never been really good at C# and I am trying to better myself by learing new things. I am now trying lambda's.

this is my code so far:

```
public static Func<float[], bool[]> CategoricalMap(Func<float, bool> mapper)
    {
        Func<float[], bool[]> fun = x => new bool[] { true };
        return fun;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<float, bool> success = x => x == 5.5f;
        var result = CategoricalMap(success)(new float[] { 4f, 5.5f, 3.5f, -5.5f, 10.2f });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

What I am trying to do is, to check what number is equal to 5.5f, but I don't know how to get the floats to show up in the CategoricalMap function. I know a bit of the puzzle, I have to do this:

```
mapper(float);
```

but I don't know how to get the floats from result to the function.
Please help.

Edit 1

I think I should make things more clear, A few weeks ago asked a someone to give me lambda challenges, sadly I have no way of contacting him. (kinda stupid of me)
this is what he gave me:

Create the lambda success which returns true if the given value is above or equal to 5.5f

Create the following function:
CategoricalMap
Creates a mapper function
Input: `mapper` a function of type `Func<float, bool>` 
Output: a function of type  `Func<float[], bool[]>` that takes in an array of booleans and applies the function `mapper` to each of the elements and stores the results in an integer array

Comment: This seems very overly complicated for something you could do with linq. `var matching = { 4f, 5.5f, 3.5f, ... }.Where(x => x == 5.5f);`

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah I know I just wanted to try it without using linq, I learn more this way.

Comment: You seem to be using lambdas _for the sake of using lambdas_. In other words, I don't see why lambdas are needed here. `bool[] CategoricalMap(float someFloat, float[] floatArray)` would suffice, wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh wait, are you trying to reinvent `Select`?

Comment: @Sweeper well yes I am using lamdas for the sake of using lamdas, I said I was trying to learn something

Comment: So I'm guessing you expect `result` to be `false, true, false, false, false`? Hint: you need a _loop_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Func<float[], bool[]> fun = x => new bool[] { true };
```

There `x` is your argument and it has type `float[]`. So in fact it is an array which you can iterate:

```
Func<float[], bool[]> fun = x => { 
   var result = new bool[x.Length];
   for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i) {
      result[i] = mapper(x[i]);
   } 
   return result;
};
```

Now you can use it as

```
public static Func<float[], bool[]> CategoricalMap(Func<float, bool> mapper)
{
   Func<float[], bool[]> fun = x => { 
      var result = new bool[x.Length];
      for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i) {
         result[i] = mapper(x[i]);
      }
      return result;
   };
   return fun;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Func<float, bool> success = x => x == 5.5f;
    var result = CategoricalMap(success)(new float[] { 4f, 5.5f, 3.5f, -5.5f, 10.2f });
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But don't do that. This approach is terrible.